# Flexbox optimal fill

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a basic flexbox column-wrap layout with a fixed width container and fixed width variable height elements inside it.

```js
for (let e of document.getElementsByClassName('element')) {
  e.style.height = Math.floor(20 + Math.random() * 50) + 'px';
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
  /*   height: 160px; */
}

.element {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
</div>
```

Browser lays it out in a single column, which is pretty logical.

Now, if I uncomment `height: 160px` definition in `#container`'s css, it lays it out in an optimal way (if you're lucky enough to catch a good set of random heights, but I hope that's enough to demonstrate the behavior). Container is optimally filled in horizontal direction, does not overflow and does not have any excess space in the bottom part.

The problem is I don't know the number of elements and their heights at this point (well, I do, but not in css). There may be just a single element or 100s of them.

Is it possible to auto-adjust container height to some optimal value to fit as many elements by width as possible using pure css? If no, is there a simple way to achieve that with JS?

Code Source: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/s0me0ne-unkn0wn/pen/LYYoPoo)

Comment: Could `flex-direction: row; height: auto;` of `#container` do the job? As I understood that's what you achieve with fixed height and as you said it's `optimal way`.

Comment: @AndreyMedvedev but elements flow direction would differ then. I need it to be columnish, not rowish

Comment: An element cannot wrap without a fixed height

Comment: column-css might be what you look for : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvvbvyp  infos https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: @G-Cyr after come experiments I used you solution which does exactly what I need although having some caveats. Feel free to post it as answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Column CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) seems to be what you are looking for. no need to set an `height`. You can set a single rule such as a `column-count` or `column-width` . it will be filled columns by columns.

possible demo from your code setting only a `column-width` or a responsive variant : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvvbvyp :

```js
for (let e of document.getElementsByClassName('element')) {
  e.style.height = Math.floor(20 + Math.random() * 50) + 'px';
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  column-width: 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
}

.element {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
</div>
```

see:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns
>
> CSS Multi-column Layout is a module of CSS that adds support for multi-column layouts. Support is included for establishing the number of columns in a layout, as well as how content should flow from column to column, gap sizes between columns, and column dividing lines (known as column rules) along with their appearance.